# Visual Studio Installer 2019 Community 16.9 crash

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

During update Visual Studio 2019 to latest version (16.9), setup failed. Stupidly I closed installer window without read the error.
When I retryed the update, the Installer crashes few seconds after start.
I have uninstalled wholly Visual Studio, but Installer still crash.
I think something is left dirty after first update fail, I tried to search in log files recoverd by collect.exe tools, but I can't found usefull information in that bilions of messages.
Reinstalling Windows must be the last choice, there is a way to take crash error for undertand the problem and search for a solution?

**EDIT**

Also InstallCleanup.exe don't solve the problem

Comment: Did you try both install flags? `-f` and `-i`?

Comment: @Casey vs_community and all .exe in installer installation folder, don't recognize -i parameter. At what command do you refer?

Comment: @MrWolf Whoops, that was a typo. Supposed to be when running `InstallCleaner`, did you try both the `-i` and then `-f` flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Installer version 2.9.3349 has problems with culture "it-IT". If that's your case (as it is mine), there is a workaround here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-Installer-crashes-after-up/1356122

The workaround is to force a working locale: `./vs_installer.exe --locale en-US`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Got the same problem here, and fixed through the suggested workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If you think your install and/or installer is corrupted, run the installation cleaner tool available at the URL below and then re-download the latest installer, from which you can get `16.9`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

---

Additionally there is a step you can try in [Troubleshooting Installation Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues), specifically [Step 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2019#step-4---delete-the-visual-studio-installer-directory-to-fix-upgrade-problems) (The advice above the break is actually Step 6 in this process)

> ### Step 4 - Delete the Visual Studio Installer directory to fix upgrade problems
>
> The Visual Studio Installer bootstrapper is a minimal light-weight executable that installs the rest of the Visual Studio Installer. Deleting Visual Studio Installer files and then rerunning the bootstrapper might solve some update failures.
>
> > Note
> >
> > Performing the following actions reinstalls the Visual Studio Installer files and resets the installation metadata.
>
> 1. Close the Visual Studio Installer.
> 2. Delete the Visual Studio Installer directory. Typically, the directory is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer.
> 3. Run the Visual Studio Installer bootstrapper. You might find the bootstrapper in your Downloads folder with a file name that follows a vs_[Visual Studio edition]__*.exe pattern. If you don't find that application, you can download the bootstrapper by going to the Visual Studio downloads page and clicking Download for your edition of Visual Studio. Then, run the executable to reset your installation metadata.
> 4. Try to install or update Visual Studio again. If the Installer continues to fail, go to the next step.

Comment: setup file is vs_community__1385386307.1607449921.exe, and as you say, his version is 16.9

Comment: @MrWolf See Edit

Comment: I already followed all steps at "Troubleshoot Visual Studio installation and upgrade issues" page

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the installer again for the offline installation *eg.**vs_enterprise.exe***  then run **vs_enterprise.exe --layout** "***folder where you have the offline installation***". The new installer needs to download a different new configuration file **vs_installer.version.json**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019